# How to get Text from dynamically generated text fields stored in ArrayList<Node>?

Tags: java, javafx

I have stored text fields in an `ArrayList<TextField>` dynamically after getting input from user. Every textfield has unique id associated with it. How should i get the text entered in textfields?

i already tried `getText()` in many variations inside loop, but nothing seems working!

```
// function to populate arrayList<textfield> inside support class

public ArrayList<TextField> calculateNeuMonths(int sMonth, int year, int eMonth {
    cpMonthsList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    for(int i=sMonth;i<=eMonth;i++) {
         TextField tf = new TextField();        
         tf.setId((i)+"/"+year);
         cpMonthsList.add(tf);
    }
    return cpMonthsList;
}

// the cpMonthsList textfields are already added to layout after above function

//Inside main class called this function from fxml button
public void setClick() {
    ArrayList<TextField> cp = new ArrayList<TextField>();
    cp = calculateNeuMonths(1,2,3);
    for(TextField tf : cp) {
         System.out.println(tf.getText());
    }
}
```

When `setClick()` method is called it should get text from dynamically generated text fields which are stored in arraylist with unique id and print it, but its not working, somebody!!?

Comment: When you say that "its not working", what do you mean ? Does it return you an error ?

Comment: Inside setClick, no need for double initialization of cp. You could just initialize on decleration

Comment: You don't seem to be putting the text fields anywhere for the user to enter values. In `setClick` you just create them (through the `calculateNeuMonths` method) and then immediately print their values.  I suspect you need to create them elsewhere and add them to a panel.

Comment: @Fifi it is not showing any error, it just doesn't printing results

Comment: @Neo these lists are in different classes and in different files, if i don't initialize it throws NullPointerException

Comment: @sprinter i added them to scene in another method using same list and then when i click a button this setClick() should get value from text fields

Comment: @ShubhamSharma did you try to use a debugger to see if you enter in the `for` loop inside `setClick()` ?

Comment: @Fifi i tried to print the size of list it outputs 0, but the textfields are being added to list because they are visible at runtime

Comment: @ShubhamSharma so the problem seems to be inside `calculateNeuMonths()`. Do you enter in the other `for` loop ?

Comment: @Fifi thank you the problem was in calculateNeuMonths() where i was trying to return array list of type node but the method defines to return textfield array list

Comment: The fact that you're adding the `TextField`s to the scene somewhere does not change the fact that you create a new list of `TextField`s immediately before trying to read the data. It won't be possible for the user to input anything before you read the data: the nodes aren't even part of a scene at the time you try to read the data... As already mentioned initializing `cp` with a `ArrayList` only to overwrite this value before doing anything that list object is pointless...

Answer (score -2):

Solved:
 The error was in calculateNeuMonth() i was trying to return node type arraylist but the method requires textfield return type